# Get NCBI taxIDs under a given taxID

Tags: python-3.x, taxonomy, ncbi

Somewhat similar to this thread:

[How can I get taxonomic rank names from taxid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867631/how-can-i-get-taxonomic-rank-names-from-taxid)

I have a taxID for a genus and I want to pull all taxIDs or accession numbers below that genus. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 4):

ETE toolkit can help here too. The "getting descendant taxa" section of [ETEtoolkit tutorial](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_ncbitaxonomy.html) is what you need. See link for more details. Relevant code below.

For example genus taxID 171 (leptospira)

```
from ete3 import NCBITaxa
ncbi = NCBITaxa()
descendants = ncbi.get_descendant_taxa(171)
# to print names of the taxIDs in the descendants
print(ncbi.translate_to_names(descendants))
```